# I am stuck with recursion in Power Set using Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program to return a set of subset of number.
For example: `list = [1,2,3]`
my desired function will return `[[], [1], [2], [2,1], [3], [3,1], [3,2], [3,2,1]]`
However, it returns `[[], [1], [2], [3]]`
Here is my code

```
# Write a powerSet function
def powerSet(list):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return [[]];
    else:
        temp = list.pop()
    return powerSet(list) + [[temp] + x for x in powerSet(list)];

list = [1,2,3];
print(powerSet(list));
```

Comment: `list` is a built-in, hence a poor choice for a variable name. Also -- `pop()` destructively mutates the passed list -- you should be modifying *copies* of it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you mutate the `list` object, so the two `powerSet` in the last line will not receive the same list (for example, in the first call, the first `powerSet` will get `[1,2]` but the second one will get `[1]`).

The solution is to copy the `list` when passing it down:

```
powerSet(list[:]) + [[temp] + x for x in powerSet(list[:])]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in package for "subset"

```
import itertools

def subset(x):
    all_list = []
    for i in range(len(x)+1):
        all_list+=list(itertools.combinations(x,i))
    return all_list

print subset([1,2,3])
[output>>>] [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you; however, I think there is another way to solve this problem, but I will have to go from the beginning of the set instead of the end

Comment: def p(l):if len(l) == 0: return [[]]
 #print(p(l[1:]) + [[l[0]] + x for x in p(l[1:])])
 return p(l[1:]) + [[l[0]] + x for x in p(l[1:])]

    s = [1,2,3]
    print(p(s));

Comment: Recursion is not easy to understand I think.. So thank you for the opportunity to study it. By the way, it is interesting to use "yield" and we can learn how python implement permutation and combination from https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations