# Itertools compress

Tags: python, string, loops

I am trying to extract all the words that are possible within a string as part of vocabulary game.  Consider the string "driver".  I would like to find all the English words that can be formed by using the available letters from left to right.
From “driver” we could extract drive, dive, river & die.
But we could not extract “rid” because is not all the letter appears in order from left to right.
For now I would be content of extracting all the letter combination disregarding whether or not it is a word.
I was considering using a loop to extract binary pattern

- 1=“r”
- 10=“e”
- 11=“re”
- 100=“v”
- 101=“vr”
- 110=“ve”
- 111=“ver”
- 1000=“i”
- 1001=”ir”
- 1010=”ie”
- 1011=”ier”
- 1100=”iv”
- 1101=”ivr”
- 1110=”ive”
- 1111=”iver”
- …
- 111110=”drive”

Please help!

Thank-you

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Look up how to get a "power set"; make sure you preserve the order of elements (most such algorithms do so).  That gives your list of strings.

Comment: I suggest adding some code you have tried and why it did not work or resources you found, and why they did not solved your issue.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104939/i-am-stuck-with-recursion-in-power-set-using-python help?

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel.  That link led to knowing more about iterations and itertools.  I have found my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Simple maths suggests that the approach you have is the best possible approach there is.
Since index i can either be present or absent, hence the number of combinations will be 2^n (since we are not shuffling).

Comment: You've missed the point; OP wants to know how to write code to solve the problem. But right now, the question should not be answered, because it does not meet the question requirements.

Comment: No, OP is looking for an algorithmic solution that is better than the one they suggested. I simply said that a better solution is mathematically impossible.

Comment: OP understands that they have to iterate from 0 to 2^n and the binary format of the i'th number will represent the indices of the ith permutation.

Comment: Thanks @HarshAnand.  Your comments have guided me towards a functional solution.

Comment: @DanielGaulin np! consider accepting the solution.